# What is fancier way to write $y = k_1x_1+k_2x_2+k_3x_3+k_4x_1x_2+k_5x_1x_3+k_6x_2x_3+k_7x_1x_2x_3$?

Tags: notation

How to write a function $y = k_1x_1+k_2x_2+k_3x_3+k_4x_1x_2+k_5x_1x_3+k_6x_2x_3+k_7x_1x_2x_3$ (sum of all three variable combinations) more compactly?

Comment: Serious question: why do you want to do this?  If you're writing a proof and don't need to refer to the coefficients individually, you can just call it $p(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.  If you're in search of maximally dense notation for its own sake, Alex's answer is good.  If your polynomial has certain extra properties (e.g., symmetric), you can express it in terms of other polynomials and reduce the number of terms.

Answer (score 5):

In the expression below, $[3] = \{1,2,3\}$, and the $k$s are indexed by the $7$ nonempty subsets of $[3]$ directly, rather than by the numbers $1$ through $7$.

$$\sum_{\emptyset\neq X\subseteq [3]} \left( k_X \prod_{i\in X} x_i\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

By introducing a few notations, we can simplify Alex's answer.

Let $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and for $\alpha \subseteq \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ define $x^\alpha = \prod_{i\in\alpha} x_i$ and let $|\alpha|$ be the number of elements in $\alpha$. Then we can write
$$y = \sum_{1 \leq |\alpha| \leq 3} k_\alpha x^\alpha$$

This is heavily inspired by [multi-index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation).